# What is the biblical basis for the idea that God stores our prayers?

Tags: biblical-basis, prayer

I've heard that God stores our prayers. Where does He store them; is it in a bottle, a scroll, a book? What scripture supports this claim?

Comment: where did you hear this? are you looking for a particular denomination's point of view?

Comment: On the cloud of course

Comment: Why would God need to record our prayers? So that He might not forget them?

Comment: @Wtrmute "But I say unto you, That every idle word that men shall speak, they shall give account thereof in the day of judgment." Matthew 12:36 God does keeps records; for instance, Christians are written in the Lamb's book of life, Revelation 21:27.

Comment: @depperm No, I'm not looking for a particular denomination's point of view, just scripture.

Comment: @Breakskater That passage says nothing of there being a record, only that we will be called to give account. Because God lives outside of time, He sees all moments at once, and thus does not need to "remind Himself" of anything anyone has ever done. Also, it's difficult to take any passage of Revelation at face value, since there's so much symbolism and metaphor in it: there's no reason to assume that the Book of Life is a physical book.

Comment: @Wtrmute Exodus 32:33, "The LORD said to Moses, "Whoever has sinned against Me, I will blot him out of My book." There are several other books in the Bible that mention the book of life. It is not safe to assume that the book of life is simply a metaphor when it is mentioned throughout the bible and not only Revelation

Comment: @Breakskater: Again, this can and often is construed as a metaphor; blotting out of His book, in this case, is in the same class of imagery as God deciding to no longer hide His face from His people in Ez 39:29, or the references to "those who sleep" when St Paul speaks of the dead. But of course, if you _must_ interpret this literally, ask for the point of view of _Fundamentalists_ or other such biblical literalists. As it stands, my comment reflects Catholic and Anglican thinking, for instance, though it is certainly _not_ what you're looking for.

Comment: @Wtrmute: Hold on there, big guy; them's fightin' words! I'm a Fundamentalist, as we all are when you stop to think about. We just draw our theological and biblical lines in different places and for different reasons. For example, I proudly consider myself a Fundamentalist, but I'm from being a literalist in interpreting the Bible. As a rhetorician, I'm bold enough to suggest that language is probably more figurative than literal. It 's just that we take the figurative for granted all the time. For example, when you tell someone you understand what they just said, you might say, "I see!"

Comment: Then I would ask, "What exactly do you see? Are you talking literally?" Then you might say, "Oh, I see what you mean." Then I would say, "No, I don't think you do." Then you might say . . .." Well, you get the point. Jesus said he was the door to the sheepfold, but he wasn't made of wood and he didn't have hinges and a doorknob attached to him. I consider myself a fisher of men, but I don't fish for them with a hook, a tackle box, or a net. I do, however, put out bait in the form of leading questions, loving deeds, and good listening skills. I rest my case. Selah.

Comment: @rhetorician: I did not nean to offend; it was my experience with _self-described_ Fundamentalists that their exegesis tends to be a lot more literalist than, say, Anglicans or Orthodox. That being said, I did not mean that Fundamentalists read _the whole Bible_ literally. If I came across as such, I'll formally retract myself

Comment: @Wtrmute: No offense taken. I feel very strongly, however, about how loosely Christ's enemies (e.g., strident atheists) use the term "fundamentalist" as a virtual curse word. What they do not realize is that they themselves are fundamentalists; they just draw their fundamental dividing lines (viz., their presuppositions) a little differently! Cheers, and happy Easter. Don

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're learning about are advanced topics, which we discuss in a church full of prayer warriors. We're advanced in our Christian journeys in life with God.

The angels have abilities to transport items from Earth to Heaven. Prayers are taken up in bowls. Bottles are for storing tears, which people cry when they pray. Our lives are recorded in books in Heaven. Each person has a book with their name on it. It contains the deeds of what you've done in your life. All of them. When you ask Jesus to forgive you for your sins, He has angels take your book from a library & wipe over your sins with His blood. Thus God can't see your sins, because all He'd see in your book is His blood & your good deeds, which remain. If you become a prayer warrior, you can actually see Heaven & hell before death. You may not want to believe now, but when you start to experience supernatural things through prayer & faith, then you'll understand & believe.

Here are some scriptures for you:

[Psalm 56:8 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2056:8&version=NKJV) talks about tears being put into a bottle & a book

> You number my wanderings; Put my tears into Your bottle; Are they not
>   in Your book?

Both Revelation & Daniel discuss the books with our deeds in them:

[Revelation 20:12 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2020%3A12&version=NKJV)

> And I saw the dead, small and great, standing before God, and books
>   were opened. And another book was opened, which is the Book of Life.
>   And the dead were judged according to their works, by the things which
>   were written in the books.

This is also found in [Daniel 7:10 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%207:10&version=NKJV)

> A fiery stream issued And came forth from before Him. A thousand
>   thousands ministered to Him; Ten thousand times ten thousand stood
>   before Him. The court was seated, And the books were opened.

Regarding prayers, which angels carry to God:

[Revelation 8:3-4 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%208%3A3-4&version=NKJV) discusses those.

> 3 Then another angel, having a golden censer, came and stood at the
>   altar. He was given much incense, that he should offer it with the
>   prayers of all the saints upon the golden altar which was before the
>   throne. 4 And the smoke of the incense, with the prayers of the
>   saints, ascended before God from the angel’s hand.

To find the bowl, we use this verse from [Revelation 5:8 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%205:8&version=NKJV):

> Now when He had taken the scroll, the four living creatures and the
>   twenty-four elders fell down before the Lamb, each having a harp, and
>   golden bowls full of incense, which are the prayers of the saints.

So we see that prayers are stored in golden bowls in Heaven. Our deeds are stored in books. Our prayerful tears are stored in bottles.

Whenever you're ready, check out some of the prayer warrior testimonies at: http://www.divinerevelations.info

God bless you! I hope that you'll continue to learn about Him! Someday, you'll find rewards in Heaven!

Answer (score 2):

Apocalipsis 8:4
Y el humo del incienso subió de la mano del ángel delante de Dios, con las oraciones de los santos.

English version(NAB) of Revelation 8:3-4

> 3  Another angel came and stood at the altar, holding a gold censer.
>   He was given a great quantity of incense to offer, along with the
>   prayers of all the holy ones, on the gold altar that was before the
>   throne.    4  The smoke of the incense along with the prayers of the
>   holy ones went up before God from the hand of the angel.

Comment: This site uses English.  Please have a friend help you convert your answer into English.

Comment: @zayda, Thanks. This verse tells me that the angel was somehow holding prayers. Who are the holy ones that the verse is speaking of? Is it saved Christians?

Comment: Gracias Zayda. Esta Bien. Would you like me to translate for you @KorvinStarmast ?

Answer (score 2):

Acts 10 King James Version (KJV)

*1 There was a certain man in Caesarea called Cornelius, a centurion of the band called the Italian band,

2 A devout man, and one that feared God with all his house, which gave much alms to the people, and prayed to God alway.

3 He saw in a vision evidently about the ninth hour of the day an angel of God coming in to him, and saying unto him, Cornelius.

4 And when he looked on him, he was afraid, and said, What is it, Lord? And he said unto him, Thy prayers and thine alms are come up for a memorial before God.

5 And now send men to Joppa, and call for one Simon, whose surname is Peter:

6 He lodgeth with one Simon a tanner, whose house is by the sea side: he shall tell thee what thou oughtest to do.*

At this point in time this man was not considered saved.  But he approached God in such a way with his life, his substance and his prayers pleased God to the point that preserved them before him and rememberd him.

No doubt God perceives the things that we do that please him for an appointed time to remember us and reward and grant our petition...